# Use Python SciPy to compute the Rodrigues formula P_n(x) (Legendre polynomials)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to use Python to calculate the Rodrigues formula, P_n(x).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_formula

That is, I would like a function which takes into two input parameters, n and x, and returns the output of this formula.

However, I don't think SciPy has this function yet. SpiPy does offer a Legendre module:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.polynomials.legendre.html

I don't think any of these is the Rodrigues formula. Am I wrong?

Is there a standard way SciPy offers to do this?

EDIT: I would like the input parameters to be arrays, not just single input values.

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.polynomials.legendre.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you simply want P_n(x), then you can create a suitable object representing the P_n polynomial using `scipy.special.legendre` and call it with your values of `x`:

```
In [1]: from scipy.special import legendre
In [2]: n = 3
In [3]: Pn = legendre(n)
In [4]: Pn(2.5)
Out[4]: 35.3125        # P_3(2.5)
```

The object `Pn` is, in a sense, the "output" of the Rodrigues formula: it is a polynomial of the required order, which can be evaluated at a provided value of `x`. If you want a single function that takes `n` and `x`, you can use [`eval_legendre`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.special.eval_legendre.html):

```
In [5]: from scipy.special import eval_legendre
In [6]: eval_legendre(3, 2.5)
Out[6]: 35.3125
```

As noted in [the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/special.html), this is the recommended way to do it for large-ish `n` (e.g. `n > 20`), instead of creating a polynomial object with all the coefficients which does not handle rounding errors and numerical stability as well.

EDIT: Both approaches work with arrays (at least for the `x` argument). For example:

```
In [7]: x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 5, 10])
In [8]: Pn(x)
Out[8]: 
array([  0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   1.70000000e+01,
     3.05000000e+02,   2.48500000e+03])
```

Comment: It would be nice if I could get something that works with n as an array as well. This is a great start though. Thanks!

Comment: [scipy.special.eval_legendre](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.special.eval_legendre.html)

Comment: Thanks, @pv: I'd forgotten about the `eval_` methods: edited.

Comment: If you only need function values, and not the power basis representation and roots etc., using `eval_legendre` is recommended (try `legendre(1000)(0.1)` and `eval_legendre(1000, 0.1)`). Then read the warning notice in the documentation, and look at `x=0.1*legendre(50); print(x(0.9), 0.1*legendre(50)(0.9), 0.1*eval_legendre(50, 0.9))`

Comment: This warning is well-made, though I don't know whether it applies to OP's use-case. I've edited in a few comments, but if you have anything to add feel free to edit or add an answer yourself.